# ng-table 1.0.0 set to specific page stops grid from paging

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

I've been trying to upgrade our `ng-Table` code to either .083 as well as 1.0.0 but keep getting the same problem. Basically my goal is in certain situations to specifically set the page of my table to a specific page instead of defaulting to page 1.

An example would be if I was on page 3 and clicked on a table item which would take me to another partial page and I wanted to return to the same place in the table (ie: page 3 instead of 1).

When I evaluate the condition I merely set the page with the following line of code:

```
params.page(3)
```

As soon as this code executes it doesn't error (in the console) but my table will no longer page using my custom pager. It does really weird things like jumps pages as well as the data does not change in the grid. Sometimes my pager prev/next buttons disappear altogether or they jump from page 2 to 4. This same code worked flawlessly when using ng-table 0.4.1 and prior. I've looked everywhere but don't see anyone else with this problem. I've seen tons of examples where someone desires to do this but not in the newer versions of ng-table 0.8.3 forward.

Below is a simple example (with extra code removed to simplify my example).

[image: Controller code for ng-table where the params.page(3) breaks paging]

Comment: Please post a code sample and not an image of code. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Just resolved the issue. For some reason now when you put the params.page(3) within the "getData" it will do some weird stuff and not work. I moved this code "within the promise" but outside the "getData" and all works fine. This problem was only occurring when setting to a specific page and not when setting a filter. So now I store the page and filter last applied within the "getData" but I apply its value outside the getData.

Comment: If you think this could serve someone else, you should edit the question to include the code, answer the question and mark it as accepted. Otherwise, delete the question, as in this state, I doubt it will be useful to the site.